# Python dateutil 1.5 package installation error

Tags: python

I removed my python `dateutil 2.7` package and when I install python `dateutil-1.5` package it makes the below error.

In my project folder I have the version `cd openerp-7.0-20130302-002131/`

When I give the below command it gives the error.

```
sudo python setup.py install

error: python-dateutil 1.5 is installed but python-dateutil>=2.4.0 is required by set(['vobject'])
```

Kindly give the solution to this problem.

Comment: Er, install 2.4.0?

Comment: why you need `dateutil 1.5` ? it seems that it would be better to use `dateutil 2.4.0` ...?

Comment: I am going to work with another project. It only accepts the dateutil 1.5. So i need to install dateutil 1.5